# How to filter mysql with two duplicated variables

Tags: mysql

I have table like this:

```
id  name    start_date  
1   abc     2019-12-27
1   asd     2019-12-27
1   dwq     2019-12-27
1   sre     2019-12-27
1   ers     2019-12-27
1   fas     2019-12-23
1   abc     2019-12-23
1   dwq     2019-12-23
2   wda     2019-12-23
2   wqw     2019-12-23
2   rew     2019-12-19
2   sdf     2019-12-19
2   vfd     2019-12-19
2   asd     2019-12-19
```

And I want to filter it in a way, that I get all records with ID 1 and highest date. When I did this:

```
SELECT id,MAX(start_date),name FROM table1 WHERE id=1 GROUP BY name;
```

I got this result:

```
1   abc     2019-12-27
1   asd     2019-12-27
1   dwq     2019-12-27
1   sre     2019-12-27
1   ers     2019-12-27
1   fas     2019-12-23
```

There is an additional row with name 'fas' and I am guessing that it is shown because the name is unique for 2019-12-23 date. How to filter it properly?

EDIT: I have duplicates in two columns - ID and start_date. For single ID there can be multiple dates and of course one date can have multiple IDs. But what I want to get are fields with specific ID and highest possible start_date.

Comment: Does you need only those `name` which highest date is equal to the highest date for `id=1`? If so you must obtain this max_date in a subquery and use it for filtering.

Comment: Sometimes it's best to wait a while before accepting an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [DISTINCT] *
FROM table1 
WHERE id = 1
  AND start_date = ( SELECT MAX(start_date)
                     FROM table1
                     WHERE id = 1 )
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is a contradiction - well, an oxymoron or a tautology, depending upon your point of view.

Comment: @Strawberry As you can see `[DISTINCT]` is wrapped. I mean that if the source data contains duplicates (DDL is not shown) but OP do not need in them then he must use DISTINCT, and, of course, in such case he should specify fieldnames (syntax do not allow asterisk with DISTINCT). If you don't know this, well, consider it an oxymoron.

Comment: If the source data contains duplicates, then the OP has bigger problems that first need to be addressed.

Comment: I have duplicates in two columns - ID and start_date. For single ID there can be multiple dates and of course one date can have multiple IDs. But what I want to get are fields with specific ID and highest possible start_date.

Comment: @janoe Edit your question. Add this facts (and table's DDL) into it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table1 t 
WHERE t.id = 1 
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table1
  WHERE id = t.id AND start_date > t.start_date
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/udJ7GQ7AHXYi7HWwWb3c4f/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name | start_date          |
| --- | ---- | ------------------- |
| 1   | abc  | 2019-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 1   | asd  | 2019-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 1   | dwq  | 2019-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 1   | sre  | 2019-12-27 00:00:00 |
| 1   | ers  | 2019-12-27 00:00:00 |
```